# Powershell list members in sub groups in a AD group

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and still learning. What I'm trying to do is search for a list of all members within an AD group and if there's a group within that original group to show those members as well and so on. For ex:

**Server:** "LocalZoo"

- **Local Admin Members:**

  - Central/Main Admin
  - East/Cold Admin
  - West/Hot Admin
  - East/Bob
  - East/Emily
  - West/John
  - Central/Will

**SubGroup:** Central/Main Admin

- **Members:**

  - Central/Will
  - Central/Nick
  - Central/Rose

**SubGroup:** East/Cold Admin

- **Members:**

  - East/Bob
  - East/Jess
  - East/Zoo Animal
- **SubGroup:** East/Zoo Animal

  - **Members:**
  - East/Polar Bear
  - East/Seel

**SubGroup:** West/Hot Admin

- **Members:**

  - West/Rick
  - West/Morty

So far I am able to use this code to obtain a list of members within the 1st group but unsure how to go further.

```html
function get-localadmins{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
  [string]$computerName
  )
  $group = get-wmiobject win32_group -ComputerName $computerName -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'"
  $query = "GroupComponent = `"Win32_Group.Domain='$($group.domain)'`,Name='$($group.name)'`""
  $list = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser -ComputerName $computerName -Filter $query
  $list | %{$_.PartComponent} | % {$_.substring($_.lastindexof("Domain=") + 7).replace("`",Name=`"","\")}
}

$Server = Read-Host "Server Name"
get-localadmins $Server
```

Comment: Are you interested in _local_ groups on the respective computers, or are you interested in groups maintained by ActiveDirectory (domain groups)?

Comment: When I use the script I would type in the FQDN and it would show me the local group on the computer, as would AD. But doesn't show who's under the subgroup stated. So I would have to search in again in AD to see which members are under the sub groups.

So I think I'm interested in the domain groups that would show members within the sub group from the main group that's being searched.

Comment: So you have to deal with both local and AD groups? If you're dealing only with AD groups, you can use `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity rootgroup -Recurse` to accomplish the search.

Comment: Yes so when I search for "LocalZoo" server, it would show the local admin groups and members. But doesn't display the members of the groups from the result of the local admin.

Comment: Then you'll have to determine somehow which members of the root local group are also local groups and process them individually; your AD groups can be processed using `Get-ADGroupMember` as above.

Comment: This question was also [asked on the MS TechNet forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/70862d71-d5cf-4ddb-af6a-56a292ae2436/get-local-group-members?forum=winserverpowershell), and had an accepted answer

Comment: Ohhh thank you, that's perfect. It shows all the members in all subgroups. After I modify it a bit to just display the user's account, it's a great list. Now just need to change it to display the group they each belong to :)